# forming WP_Query for posts of all post types but from specific categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query

I need to get post from blog, custom post type 1, custom post type 2. custom post type 3 and either from category 1 or category 2 or category 3 or category 4 or category 5 or category 6 or category 7 or category 8. I have this but isn't working. I get no results, no errors either.

```
<?php 

    function filter_where_categs() {
        $where .= " AND (category_name => array('black-star-crescent-moon', 'audio', 'blackward', 'ghost', 'protect', 'remember', 'return', 'video'))";
        return $where;
    }

    $args=array(
        'post_type'=> array( 'test-bscm', 'post', 'test-btum', 'test-other' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 19
    );

    $temp = $wp_query; 
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_categs');
    $wp_query->query($args);

?>
```

Comment: are you using the default category taxonomy for all your custom post types?

Answer (score 1):

According to the codex category_name only takes one string value. `category_in` accepts an array of category IDs:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
 'category__in' = array(1,4,6,8), // use IDs
 'post_type'=> array( $ptype, 'post', 'test-btum', 'test-other' )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

It might be possible that the default category taxonomy is not registered to your custom post type. In that case try adding

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'test-btum' )
```

to your themes `functions.php`. Repeat for every post type you want to register. Make sure your custom post types are actually assigned to a category otherwise they won't show up in your query.

Comment: @JanBeck. thanks. category_in yielded the same results as category_name, which i tried after this question. so it works. but it is not giving me the results that i need. it returned posts for the 'post' post type only and not for any other post type. so your previous question is important. i'm not sure if i'm using default category taxonimoies. when i looked at the categories i needed for all the post types, all post types have exactly the same categories, they all had the same ID. i'm using a theme that has an interface that creates custom post types and their respective categories.

Comment: @JanBeck.thanks again. register_taxonomy_for_object_type didn't change the results. still only getting posts from blog that match the cat ID's

Comment: @JanBeck. thanks again. register_taxonomy_for_object_type yielded posts from blog that match the cat ID's. is this function supposed to add a meta box with the Blog categories in the other custom post types?